# Setting a size for a label border

Tags: c#, winforms, label, border

I made a grid of 9 by 9 labels and each label has a border. After each 3 labels in a row/column I want the border to be thicker then the previous ones. I can't find a way to add this size of that border.

I searched on google, but couldn't find anything useful.

Can anyone help me?

```
 private void AddNodesToGrid()
{
  pnlGrid.Controls.Clear();
  rooster = new NewLabel[9, 9];
  int Xpos = 0;
  int Ypos = 0;
  for (int I = 0; I < 9; I++)
  {
    for (int T = 0; T < 9; T++)
    {
      rooster[I, T] = new NewLabel(new Node());
      rooster[I, T].Left = Xpos;
      rooster[I, T].Top = Ypos;
      rooster[I, T].Width = 30;
      rooster[I, T].Height = 30;
      rooster[I, T].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      rooster[I, T].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
      pnlGrid.Controls.Add(rooster[I, T]);
      Xpos += 30;
    }
    Xpos = 0;
    Ypos += 30;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Winforms or WPF?

Comment: I use winforms for this project

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? Are you using `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: Is there a way to post code here ?

Comment: So is this the border of the outer labels or do you have a panel that encloses them?

Comment: @user2040386 You could edit your question and post the code

Comment: @user2040386 Of course! Edit the post, paste the code, select the whole code and press the curly braces button.

Comment: Anyways, I have panel and a method that places the labels in that panel like a grid. To be more specific I'm trying to make a sudoku solver and I want to make the custom sudoku layout. Each square of 3 by 3 had a thicker border.

Comment: @ScruffyDuck I use a panel that contains every label.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn NewLabel is a class that inherits everything from a Label. In NewLabel I have a method that add a textbox(Node) to the label.
I use this so I can give in numbers in each label.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I preferred to draw my own table. But if you need to use your labels, I advise you to paint the borders yourslef:

```
public class NewLabel : Label
{
    //...

    private int _borderWidth = 1;
    public int BorderWidth
    {
        get { return _borderWidth; }
        set
        {
            _borderWidth = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private Color _borderColor = Color.Black;
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return _borderColor; }
        set
        {
            _borderColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        int xy = 0;
        int width = this.ClientSize.Width;
        int height = this.ClientSize.Height;
        Pen pen = new Pen(_borderColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < _borderWidth; i++)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, xy + i, xy + i, width - (i << 1) - 1, height - (i << 1) - 1);
    }
}
```

Now your `NewLabel` class has `BorderWidth` and `BorderColor` properties that you can set.

(Note: The way I used to draw the border is the fastest one. Creating a pen with required width does not work well because GDI+ puts the center of the line on the specified coordinates.)

Answer (score 0):

a better way to accomplish this is to use a nested `TableLayoutPanel`. Create it from the designer and place your labels inside. Steps :

- Place a 3x3 `TableLayoutPanel` (Parent Panel).
- Place a 3x3 `TableLayoutPanel` (Child Panels) in each cell of the parent panel.
- set the `CellBorderStyle` to `Single` for parent table and child tables.
- set the `Margin` for child tables to `0,0,0,0`.

You will get this effect :

[image]

Comment: Aight, I thank you all for the help. With all this info and tips I think I can figure something out.

Thanks!